# Spotfire culture error that auto changes to default culture

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-analyst

This is the error I get when loading my embedded dashboard in Spotfire:

**Unknown culture

The analysis was saved using a formatter with the culture setting 'en-CY', which is not available on this system. Using default culture instead.**

It doesn't point to what is wrong and doesn't impact the data. How do I fix this warning notification and set everything to default originally.

Thanks